# c++ Vector memory problems

Tags: c++

The memory of my program is supposed to be < 4-16 MB. How can I optimize it? I will explain what my program does in short :

I input n, k and n numbers in the vector a. Then I store in the vector b the counts of all equal numbers found in the vector a. So, for example, if the vector a contained 1,2,2,3, the vector B would store the counts like this:

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 1
```

Then I check if these counts are divisible by k and if not, I output that number and break the loop. I know there are some things that can be optimized but how do I deal with the memory problem? This is the code below :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> a,b[1000001];
int main()
{
    int n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int k;
        cin>>k;
        a.push_back(k);
        b[a[i]].push_back(1);

    }
    for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if(b[a[i]].size() % k != 0)
        {

            cout<<a[i]<<"\n";

            break;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, representing a single number with `std::vector<int>{1, 1, ..., 1, 1}.size()` is not the most optimized way...

Answer (score 2):

don't use vector for `b`, use `std::map`. also you don't need `a` at all, just read the input, find corresponding item in `b` and increment it

EDIT:

First of all, you don't need `a` because you can analyse the input numbers "on the fly" as you read them.

So the task boils down to counting numbers and storing the result. You need to store a set of pairs where a pair is a number `i` and how many times it occurred in the input.

You used an array for this. The problem with array is that it has predefined size. Why did you use `1000001`? Try to input a number greater than `1000001` and see what happens? Also array of `1000001` vectors uses a lot of memory while most of it is wasted as with your test input of `1,2,2,3` only 3 of 1000001 items will be used.

`map` is much better here because it allows you to associate your number with its count (how many times it occurred). So `map` would contain only 3 items for your test input. A `map` looks like:

```
[key1, value1]
[key2, value2]
...
```

In your case `key` would be numbers, `value` - their count.

To count number you don't need to store `1` for each occurrence in a vector because it's very memory inefficient (lots of `1`s). You should count them like `c = c + 1` or just `++c`.

Comment: to be honest, I thought about using it. Thx

Comment: But I am not very familiar with it even though i checked it

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about it?

Answer (score 0):

This line `vector<int> a, b[1000001]` is equivalent to:

```
vector<int> a
vector<int> b[1000001];
```

The second array `b` of `vector<int>` is using a lot of memory.

And also this line `b[a[i]].push_back(1)`, you keep appending `1` to the vector b, and that will keep increasing the size of it.

What you need is:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> m;
    int n,k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int k;
        cin >> k;
        m[k]++;
    }

    for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++) {
        if (it->second % k == 0) {
            cout << it->first << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

You read more about vector and map

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: Swap 'first' and 'second'. OP said it's a homework, so instead of the final solution it would be better to help them to come out with their own

Comment: @AndyT thanks for pointing the error. Yay, was a bit lazy and find it easier to just type the code out :)